# Repeal of conditional PR in Canada

Tags: canada, pr

Some of you might have heard about the removal of the two year conditional permanent resident status for spousal visas in Canada. Here is a [news article](http://www.cbc.ca/news/politics/liberal-immigration-marriage-fraud-1.4084865) about the same. My question is if this is applicable for new visas only or is the change applicable for spouses already in Canada under the conditional two year permanent resident condition. Kindly elucidate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the official Canadian government news release on 28 April 2017: [Government of Canada Eliminates Conditional Permanent Residence for Spouses and Partners](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/news/2017/04/government_of_canadaeliminatesconditionalpermanentresidenceforsp.html)

which states in part:

> This change applies to anyone who was subject to the requirement, as
>   well as to new spouses and partners who are sponsored as permanent
>   residents.